# after introducing link in frame system giving error Failed to load resource net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: html

I have introduced frame in div which is having hyperlink in it.
when I am trying to debug the html in chrome, it is giving me an error FILE_NOT_FOUND
Please find below code

Comment: <div class="color"> <iframe src="www.xoriant.com" name="iframe_a" width="800" height="200"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.xoriant.com" target="iframe_a"><span class="format">Xoriant Web Site</span></a></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood from your question..

You must give 'http://' along with the url.

```
<div class="color"> <iframe src="http://www.xoriant.com" name="iframe_a" width="800" height="200"></iframe> <a href="http://www.xoriant.com"; target="iframe_a"><span class="format">Xoriant Web Site</span></a></div>
```

Please try this. Hope this will help you.

Have a nice day:)